# Drag and drop table rows in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I'm seeking something like
[Drag and drop rows in a jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219346/drag-and-drop-rows-in-a-jqgrid)
but for Angular 6

How to make a drag and drop row of a table and get an order of the rows
for send to server?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you check this if you can update to angular 7

https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-angular-cdk-drag-and-drop-feature-d79ba462ce31

Otherwise theres a ton of dnd libraries out there for angular like

https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-dnd

hope this helps